# Extend horizontal line to edge of figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

In the following code, I obtain a horizontal line extending within the "box" of the plot (axes object):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.patch.set_facecolor('white')
fig.patch.set_alpha(1.0)

plt.axhline(y = 155, clip_on = False)
```

This gives the following figure:
[image]

Is there a way to extend this horizontal line to the entire plot/figure? (in other words, past the "box" of the plot).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the `xmin` and `xmax` args in `plt.axhline` to be outside of the `0.0` to `1.0` range.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.patch.set_facecolor('white')
fig.patch.set_alpha(1.0)

plt.axhline(y = 155, xmin=-.1, xmax=1.1, clip_on = False)
```

[image]

Note that docstring for the `axhline` function does advise against setting these values outside of the `0` to `1` range:

> xmin : scalar, optional, default: 0
>       Should be between 0 and 1, 0 being the far left of the plot, 1 the
>       far right of the plot.
>
> xmax : scalar, optional, default: 1
>       Should be between 0 and 1, 0 being the far left of the plot, 1 the
>       far right of the plot.

So take that however you want. It may cause problems in the future but for now at least this works. (Note that I am using matplotlib versions 1.5.1 and 2.0.0 and both work)

Comment: Worked, thanks! I do wish in the future there would be more customization options built in.